# How to alter the id in Strapi

Tags: strapi

Currently I am working on Strapi for the first time, but want to connect the collection types based on id, but when I removed one for example [id 4] and added new one. It will create an [id 5]. So I thought this was a mistake I made and removed it again and now it ended with an entry [id 6]. How can I modify that so it will recreate a new one [id 4] based on the highest existing [id 3]. Check image to better understand what I mean. [image: .]

Comment: I had encountered this issue some time before and fixed by altering the database. Are there any updates on your question? Have you found an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Starpi does not have the ability to allow for changing the default id name nor does it allow you to switch the data type (such as UUID on bookshelf and integer on mongoose), support for this is being looked at for Strapi v4.

[strapi QA](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/troubleshooting.html)